# Hibernate select error on inner join

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, join

I've got an error using hibernate/HQL

my tables are table1(id, data), where id -> primary key and table2(id, anotherdata), where id -> foreign key references to table1.id.

First class ->

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Table1 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;

    @OneToOne
    private Table2 table2;
    //construct, get, set
}
```

Second class ->

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
public class Table2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "anotherdata")
    private String data;
    //get, set, construct
}
```

HQL query is **SELECT t1.id, t1.data, t2.data FROM Table1 as t1 JOIN t1.table2 as t2**

Hibernate log: **select t1.id, t1.data, t2.anotherdata from table1 t1 inner join table2 on t1.t2_id = t2.id**

this cause error *ERROR: column t1.t2__id does not exist*

in the end of this statement **"on t1.t2_id = t2.id"** i should have **"on t1.id = t2.id"** (pure sql)

How can i fix this? will be thankful for all your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, but you should change the mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Table1 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "table1", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Table2 table2;
    //construct, get, set
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
public class Table2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "anotherdata")
    private String data;
    //get, set, construct

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Table1 table1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but now i've got ClassCastException in **List<Table1> list = session.createQuery("SELECT t1.id, t1.data, t2.data FROM Table1 as t1 JOIN t1.table2 as t2").list();**

Comment: PS. solved it. my HQL return List<Object[]> where Object[0] is table1 id, ...[1] is table1 data and ..[2] is table2 id. To return List<Table1> you should use *SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1 JOIN t1.table2*